# Smtp problem like 'smtplib.SMTPConnectError: (-1, b'The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.')'

Tags: python, email, ssl, smtp

smtplib.SMTPConnectError: (-1, b'The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.')

```
 msg['Subject'] = str("Error in file".encode(), 'utf-8')
 msg['From'] = "exmpleSender@gmail.com"
 msg['To'] = "exmple@gmail.com"

s = SMTP_SSL('mail.example.kz', 993, timeout=10)
            s.set_debuglevel(1)
            try:
                s.login('example', '123456')
                s.sendmail(msg["From"], msg["To"].split(","), msg.as_string())
            finally:
                s.quit()
```

Comment: Please show the full error message and stacktrace.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/8d40d833-36ab-4b09-bdd3-8d6fc4a73c9b/imap-commands-return-quotbad-command-received-in-invalid-statequot-after-login-command-on?forum=exchange2010 See also this regarding secure/plain login and MS Exchange. And to check login vs email address

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/python/PY_TASKER/CALLS_BY_OUTSOURCE.py", line 187, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:/python/PY_TASKER/CALLS_BY_OUTSOURCE.py", line 177, in main
    s = SMTP_SSL('mail.example.kz', 993, timeout=10)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 1030, in __init__
    source_address)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 254, in __init__
    raise SMTPConnectError(code, msg)
smtplib.SMTPConnectError: (-1, b'The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.')